# Node.js process out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have written a service to download files from an external partner site. There are around 1000 files of 1 MB each. My process is going out of memory every time I reach around 800 files.

How should I identify the root cause ?

```
var request = require('sync-request');
var fs = require('graceful-fs')
function find_starting_url(xyz_category){
  feed_url = "<url>"
    response = request("GET", feed_url).getBody().toString()
    response = JSON.parse(response)
  apiListings =  response['apiGroups']['affiliate']['apiListings'] 
  starting_url = apiListings[xyz_category]['availableVariants']['v0.1.0']['get']
  return starting_url   
}

function get_all_files(feed_category, count, next_url, retry_count){
  var headers = {
    'Id': '<my_header>',
    'Token': '<my key>'
  } 

  console.log(Date())
  console.log(count)

  if(next_url){
    products_url = next_url
  }
  else{
    products_url = find_starting_url(feed_category)
  }

  try{
        var products = request("GET", products_url, {"headers": headers}).getBody().toString()
        var parsed = JSON.parse(products)
        var home = process.env.HOME
        var fd = fs.openSync(home + "/data/abc/xyz/" + feed_category + "/" + count + ".json", 'w') 
        fs.writeSync(fd, products)
        fs.closeSync(fd)
        next_url = parsed['nextUrl']
        count++;
        if(next_url){
            get_all_files(feed_category, count, next_url)
        }
  }catch(e){
        if(retry_count >= 5){
            console.log("TERRIBLE ENDING!!!", e)
        }else{
            retry_count++;
            console.log("some error... retrying ..", e)
            get_all_files(feed_category, count, next_url, retry_count)
        }
    }

}

var feed_category = process.argv[2]
get_all_files(feed_category, 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You're calling a synchronous function recursively so every single request you have and all the data from each request is retained in memory in your local variables until all of the requests are done and all the recursive calls can unwind and then finally free all the sets of local variables.  This requires monster amounts of memory (as you have discovered).

It would be best to restructure your code so that the current request is processed, written to disk and then nothing from that request is retained when it goes onto the next request.  The simplest way to do that would be to use a while loop instead of a recursive call.  In pseudo code:

```
initialize counter
while (more to do) {
    process the next item
    increment counter
}
```

I don't understand the details of what your code is trying to do well enough to propose a rewrite, but hopefully you can see how you can replace the recursion with the type of non-recursive structure above.

Comment: Alternatively he can change his code to work asynchronously. Since async code looks recursive it's possible to do it by changing just a few lines. Because async code is not technically recursive you're allowing the garbage collector to free the old variables.

Comment: @slebetman - most node.js code should be designed async (if it's in a server, not just a stand-alone program), but it is not just a matter of changing a few lines to make all this code be async because there are quite a few operations that are sync that could be async and the whole design of the flow of the code would have to be changed to make things async.  Yes, it would enable functions to return and thus be garbage collected since it wouldn't technically be recursion.  But, if this isn't server code and can do synchronous just fine, then it's easier to just change to a `while()` loop.

Comment: I have eliminated recursion from my code. However, if I fire up ps command, I see a lot of processes like this `16430 pts/0    00:00:00 sh <defunct>` . Does that mean my code is still leaving some garbage that I need to be concerned about ?

Comment: @jfriend00: in general yes it's quite hard to refactor sync code to async. But in this specific case it's easy because the `function x() {....x()}` is already an async loop design pattern (specifically it's async.series).

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are performing a recursive call to the `get_all_files` function and it's keeping the `body` variable in memory for every single execution, since every child execution needs to be completed before the memory is released.